# Como usar los radio button c#

Tags: c#

tengo un problema en la universidad que simplificado llega un momento donde la interfaz le pide al usuario si tiene tarjeta o no y no se como hacer para que realice un subproceso dependiendo su respuesta, les dejo mi codigo la interfaz y el enunciado para ver si pueden ayudarme, muchas gracias

codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

namespace Decisiones_caso_2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnProcesar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Principal();
        }

        private void BtnSalir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void Principal()
        {
            //Valores Entrada
            int CantidadCompradores = 0;
            string Nombre = "";
            double CantidadBoletas = 0;


            //Valores Salida

            double ValorPagar = 0;

            //Inicia el ciclo de control de repeticiones

            do
            {
                CantidadCompradores = int.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Digite La Cantidad De compradores", "Cantidad Compradores", null));
            } while (CantidadCompradores <= 0);
            TextCompradores.Text = CantidadCompradores.ToString("#0.00");

            for (int ContadorCompradores = 0; ContadorCompradores < CantidadCompradores; ++ContadorCompradores)
            {


                //Leer Entradas

                Nombre = Interaction.InputBox("Digite Nombre Del Comprador", "Nombre", null);
                CantidadBoletas = double.Parse(Interaction.InputBox("Digite Cantidad De Boletas Que Desee Comprar", "Total Boletas", null));


                //Mostrar Valores Leidos

                TextNombre.Text = Nombre;
                TextBoletas.Text = CantidadBoletas.ToString("#0.00");

                //llamar al subproceso que realiza los calculos

                ValorPagar = CalcularValorPagar(CantidadBoletas);


                //Mostrar Resultados
                textValorPagar.Text = ValorPagar.ToString("#0.00");
            }

        }

        // Codifique el subproceso que corresponde a su diseño
        private double CalcularValorPagar(double CantidadBoletas)
        {
            double ValorPagar = 0.0;


            if (CantidadBoletas > 5)
            {
                ValorPagar = (1 - 15 / 100.0) * CantidadBoletas * 12000;
            }

            else

            {
                if (CantidadBoletas >= 3)
                {
                    ValorPagar = (1 - 10 / 100.0) * CantidadBoletas * 12000;
                }
                else
                {
                    ValorPagar = CantidadBoletas * 12000;
                }
            }

            return (ValorPagar);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
No se como hacer funcionar los radiobuttons, he buscado tutoriales pero no entiendo como aplicarlo en este contexto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

si no malinterprete tu pregunta, para saber cual es el `RadioButton` tildado, tenes dos opciones.

La primera, es la más sencilla, usando la propiedad [Checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx)

Por ejemplo, si tuviesemos dos `RadioButton`, uno llamado `ConTarjeta` y otro `ConEfectivo`

Bastaría, con chequear cual de estos posee la propiedad `Checked` en `true`

```
 if(ConTarjeta.Checked)
    {
   MessageBox.Show("Pagó con tarjeta!");
    }
 else
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Pagó con efectivo!");
    }
```

Por otro lado, en caso de tener muchos `RadioButton` existe una solución muy interesante utilizando [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb397676(v=vs.120).aspx)

En este caso, sería algo así

```
var botonElegido = container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                                      .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

En este ejemplo, el objeto `botonElegido` sería el `RadioButton` seleccionado.

Saludos

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya supe como solucionarlo!, un abrazo desde Colombia.